# How to display Sender's name for a mail sent to broadcast outlook 2007

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm using outlook 2007 in my PC. There is a broadcast group in my institution. For the mails which are sent to broadcast group, when I open the mail, below the subject header, there is Broadcast group name and email id instead of the sender's name and email id. Is it possible to display the sender's name/email-id?[image: screenshot]
Thanks

Comment: How do you know that isn’t the sender? Each email has a “from” header and a “reply-to” header. Both can be forged or set to whatever by the sender. Maybe the sender or system sending the mail intended for it to display that way. Have you inspected the email headers to know what is actually contained in the email and to prove that it should be displaying something different than it is?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you're right. From: Broadcast-IISc <broadcast...@.....> Is this why its appearing like that? Also I noticed there is a field called 'Reply-To' where there is sender's email address. So, is it possible to display that email address?

Comment: The reply-to filed is set by the actual sender when composing the message so that replies to this message can go to another email address. According to the description in your comment, "Broadcast-IISc <broadcast...@.....>" is the real sender of the message.

Comment: Yes. I got that. Thanks. So, now I want to display the reply-to address in header. Is it possible?

Comment: Newer versions of Outlook do show this information.